# what does - if(1, true) - mean?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I came across this code:

```
if (1, true) {/*...*/}
```

What does it actually mean?
While this evaluates to true:

```
void foo(){}
...
if(1, foo()) {/*...*/}
```

this doesnt compile:

```
void foo(){}
...
if (1 == foo()) {/*...*/}
```

obviously because compiler expects foo() to return some integral value. I thought that the comma translates to some operator.
Does that comma in the if clause translate to something internally?

Comment: In the second case, I think you meant if (foo(), 1) ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Comma Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/c-comma-operator)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The comma operator simply evaluates its left operand, followed by its right operand. So an expression like

```
(1, true)
```

evaluates the `1` first, then the `true`, resulting in an expression value of `true`.

In this particular case, the use of the comma operator seems rather pointless.

Answer (score 7):

The comma operator returns the result of the right operand, and discards the result of the left operand.
Both operands are evaluated, first left, then right.

Answer (score 1):

That's the comma operator. It evaluates 1, then `true` and then checks if `true` is true, which it is, so it executes the if.

Answer (score 1):

As others have explained, this is the comma (or sequential evaluation) operator.

However, the second code snippet does not work either, see [gcc 4.3.4's output](http://ideone.com/M7JOj). The comma operator executes all its operands in left-to-right order, treating each of them as a single sub-expression and returning the value of the last expression in the chain. As `foo()` returns `void`, the expression is not correct. If your compiler accepts it, it is a violation of the language standard.

Answer (score 0):

[Comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). Evaluation from left to right. Result is the result of the right-most expression.

Comment: Yes, yes, I had it backwards, didn't have my coffee today :)